# Enable logging of Process_Command_Line for wevtutil.exe

Tags: windows, logging, windows-server

I want to start logging the Process Command Line for wevtutil.exe usage, but I'm unsure as to how this can be achieved.

At the moment it looks like the below:

```
Process Information:
    New Process ID: <process_id>
    New Process Name: <path\to\wevtutil.exe>
    Token Elevation Type: <type>
    Creator Process ID: <creator_process_id>
    Process Command Line: <-blank->
```

Can anyone tell me how to enable this, if possible?